# Current RDBS version is not supported for Magento 2.4 Installation

Tags: mysql, mariadb, vagrant, magento2, homestead

I am installing Magento 2.4 on Vagrant through command line
here is the error I got

```
Current version of RDBMS is not supported. Used Version: 10.5.8-MariaDB-1:10.5.8+maria~bionic. Supported versions: MySQL-8, MySQL-5.7, MariaDB-(10.2-10.4)
```

and here is the configurations at my Homestead.yaml

---

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/code
      to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
    - map: realityla.io
      to: /home/vagrant/code/realityla
    - map: lhm.bb
      to: /home/vagrant/code/lhm
    - map: magento.ee
      to: /home/vagrant/code/magento

databases:
    - homestead
features:
    - mysql: true
    - mariadb: true
    - postgresql: false
    - ohmyzsh: false
    - webdriver: false

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

How can I change the Mysql or MariaDB version for only my Magento Website

Comment: as a workaround, you can change di.xml, see https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/31109

Answer (score 5):

```
Current version of RDBMS is not supported. Used Version: 10.6.4-MariaDB. Supported versions: MySQL-8, MySQL-5.7, MariaDB-(10.2-10.4)
```

*PHP Version 7.4.27*

*nginx/1.21.5*

*Server version: 10.6.4-MariaDB - Homebrew*

macOS Catalina Version 10.15.7 (19H1615)

Magento Open Source 2.4.3-p1.zip

**Solution**

nano vendor/magento/framework/Test/Unit/DB/Adapter/SqlVersionProviderTest.php

```
 'MariaDB-10.6' => [
                ['version' => '10.6.4-MariaDB'],
                '10.6.'
            ],
```

add above line in in  public function executeDataProvider(): Final function will be like this

```
/**
     * @return array
     */
    public function executeDataProvider(): array
    {
        return [
            'MariaDB-10.4' => [
                ['version' => '10.4.12-MariaDB-1:10.4.12+maria~bionic'],
                '10.4.'
            ],
            'MariaDB-10.2' => [
                ['version' => '10.2.31-MariaDB-1:10.2.31+maria~bionic'],
                '10.2.'
            ],
            'MariaDB-10.6' => [
                ['version' => '10.6.4-MariaDB'],
                '10.6.'
            ],
            'MySQL-5.7' => [
                ['version' => '5.7.29'],
                SqlVersionProvider::MYSQL_5_7_VERSION,
            ],
            'MySQL-8' => [
                ['version' => '8.0.19'],
                SqlVersionProvider::MYSQL_8_0_VERSION,
            ],
            'Percona' => [
                ['version' => '5.7.29-32'],
                SqlVersionProvider::MYSQL_5_7_VERSION,
            ],
        ];
    }
```

nano app/etc/di.xml

Line no 1856 line will be something like this

```
<item name="MariaDB-(10.2-10.4)" xsi:type="string">^10\.[2-4]\.</item>
```

Change it like bellow

```
<item name="MariaDB-(10.2-10.6)" xsi:type="string">^10\.[2-6]\.</item>
```

Answer (score 3):

And here is how I found the solution, thanks,

You Can modify the file: vendor/magento/framework/Test/Unit/DB/Adapter/SqlVersionProviderTest.php (Approximately Line 109 and add the MariaDB 10.5 Version to the Array:

'MariaDB-10.5' => [
['version' => '10.5.8-MariaDB-1:10.5.8+maria~bionic'],
'10.5.'
],
and update the file: app/etc/di.xml (approximately Line 1818):

^10.[2-5].
from:

^10.[2-4].
Now I will note, it is NOT advisable to mode core files, however if you want it to run on MariaDB 10.5, that's how you can tackle it.

Answer (score 1):

1. As a temporary fix you can apply a pull request(s) from this issue #31109: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/31109
   OR
2. Wait till issue #31109 would be resolved and use MariaDB-10.4 for now